# Failing at setting up Network connections at a new Ubuntu Machine

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, configuration

yesterday I bought a Dell R710 Poweredge and today I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it. so now im stuck on the setup at Network Connections I'm trying to setup a static server but my problem is that when I'm trying to get any further it comes "Applying network config" for 30sec and then "Network configuration times out; please verify your settings." and now I cant complete the setup.

[Here my Network configuration][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRPcD.png

Comment: Hi, please try and put  the contents of the screenshot as text in your question to preserve context (so if/when the image is deleted, your question is still understandable to others).

Answer (score 0):

For subnet use `192.168.2.0/24`
Address `192.168.2.199`
Gateway `192.168.2.1`

https://www.dan.me.uk/ipsubnets is a good place to understand which subnet mask / CIDR blocks are valid for a given IP address.

Comment: I use the same gateway which I use on my Computer which is also on the same Network. And changed the Subnet as you said but now I got this https://imgur.com/a/K89EItG im really sorry Im working with ubuntu for the last 2 years but I never installed it.

Comment: Please try 255.255.255.0 and not 255.255.255.0/24.

Comment: Then I recieve this https://imgur.com/a/Dp6zJFB and I can't save it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @NGRhodes I have update my config as you said but I still get the same "Network configuration timed out; please verify your settings." I also tried via DHCP but there comes "DHCPv4 has supplied no addresses". Now I think its not anymore a software problem and more a hardware based.

Comment: @NGRhodes now I tried to install Debian and on one point of the installation it asked me for the firmware-bnx2 pack which is the firmware for the Broadcom NetXtremeII which the server has. Could also at my Ubuntu installation this pack is needed ?